# When I go to the Shading tab it's empty but shows in Layout?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

I'm trying to do texturing for my objects but when I go to the Shading tab it's just completely empty but in the Layout tab everything shows just fine. Already tried restarting Blender multiple times.

[Video showing the error](https://youtu.be/hvcqpvQbWiE)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting your model and then going to View>Frame Selected

My first guess is that maybe you're zoomed out/panned away from the model in that view?

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, I was puzzled for a while!